# laravel manually authenticate user

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-8

I want to manually login a user in laravel 8. The problem is that authentication succeeds, but the authenticated user is not stored in the session(or the session is not updated). I use the method given in de [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users).

My loginController has two methods: 1) showing the login form and 2) performing the login

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

public function login(){
    return view('auth/login');
}

public function validateLogin(LoginRequest $request){
    
    if (Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request->email, 'password'=>$request->password])) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect()->to('/');
    }      
    return back()->withErrors(['credentials' => 'Deze gegevens zijn niet bekend!']);      
    }
}
```

The controller redirects indeed to / , so the user is authenticated but after the redirect the autenticated users is unavailable, so somehow it is not stored in the session.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Why don't you use this trait? `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers`

Comment: I am using  [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticate-a-user-by-id) first I check the email and password then Authenticate the user with user id `Auth::loginUsingId($id);`

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI The trait is not available in laravel 8 without scaffolding the auth system,

Comment: @KvdLingen, Why don't you install its scafollding using `laravel ui` package?

Comment: @EsTeAa Tried to login the user after auth::attempt, but this also did not solve my problem. There must be something the scaffolding does that is not in the docs.

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI Don't like all the extra's that come with the ui.

Comment: @KvdLingen ok just copy its code from [here](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/3.x/auth-backend/AuthenticatesUsers.php)

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI Copied it, and two other traits it depends upon, but still no change. After redirect the authenticated users is still null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the id from the User model as I wanted to use the e-mailadress as the primary key. This violated the Authenticable trait so the session was not updated.

The usermodel needed the following function to replace the id with the email:

```
public function getKeyName(){
    return 'email';
}
```

The same can be accomplished with:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'email';

public $incrementing = false;
```